# ModuleSpec not found during reload for programmatically imported file in different directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

While implementing a reload function in a CLI, I stumbled across this odd error which I cannot seem to solve. To recreate this, first, create a dummy file in a different directory to your CWD. For this example, I'll call it `test.py`.

Using the recipe [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html?highlight=find_spec#importing-a-source-file-directly), import it programmatically, but ensure that the CWD is separate and the path to `test.py` cannot be reached using the CWD as a 'stem'.

```py
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('test', <path>)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules['test'] = module
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

The error occurs when trying to reload the module with `importlib.reload`:

```
>>> importlib.reload(module)

  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 168, in reload
    raise ModuleNotFoundError(f"spec not found for the module {name!r}", name=name)
ModuleNotFoundError: spec not found for the module 'test'
```

I had a little inspection of `importlib.__init__.reload` which seems to call `_frozen_importlib._bootstrap._find_spec`. The error is raised because the module spec was not found, yet the attribute `__spec__` is present before the reload. The spec is set to `None` due to the nature of the code:

```
spec = module.__spec__ = _bootstrap._find_spec(name, pkgpath, target)
if spec is None:
    raise ModuleNotFoundError(f"spec not found for the module {name!r}", name=name)
```

Is there a way for me to reload the programatically imported module? I do need to keep the file imported using a file path since the program it's a part of allows the user to write 'plugins' which can be placed anywhere in the filesystem. This is a simplified version of what's mainly going on in the import mechanics for my code.

Answer (score 2):

With a suitably recent version of python (>=3.4), you can add a `MetaPathFinder` to `sys.meta_path` to tell python where to find the module spec.  If you do this, you avoid the explicit module load recipe and `importlib.reload` should work correctly.  Example:

```
class ModuleFinder(importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder):

    def __init__(self, path_map:dict):
        self.path_map = path_map

    def find_spec(self, fullname, path, target=None):
        if not fullname in self.path_map:
            return None
        return importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(fullname, self.path_map[fullname])

    def find_module(self, fullname, path):
        return None # No need to implement, backward compatibility only

sys.meta_path.append(ModuleFinder(my_module_paths))
```

Where `my_module_paths` is some dict mapping module names to locations.

For more details: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#setting-up-an-importer
(actually this is just below where you found the recipe)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give some clarity to the situation.

What happens is the `importlib.reload(module)` calls
`_bootstrap._find_spec(name, pkgpath, target)`.  The bootstrap
part of the importlib is a frozen module so, unless we run Python
from source, we can't step into it with a debugger.  We're able
to step, however, through `reload()` and up to the failing call.
See `c:/my/python/lib/importlib/__init__.py(166)reload()` and
`c:/my/python/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py(890)_find_spec()`.

Comparing the inputs passed in from `reload()` to `_find_spec()`, we
see that the `name` passed in is "test", the `path` is the
`pkgpath` which is `None`, and the `target` is the module object for `test`.  The `name` is found in `sys.modules`, so `is_reload` is True.  Then
for each finder in the `meta_path`, its `find_spec()` function is
called. Specifically, its called with `path` which corresponds to
`pkgpath` and is equal to None.  Hence, the spec is always `None`.
The `pkgpath` is ultimately determined by the package`s parent. The module` name`is simply`test` and there is no
parent.  Since the test module lives outside the current working
directory, this will always fail.

When we add the ModuleFinder to the meta_path, its find_spec gets
called within in the `_bootstrap._find_spec(name, pkgpath, target)` line.  It then calls `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location` which was how the module was loaded in the first time.